# Projecting 3D points to an undistorted ROI using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Assume I have a camera that has been calibrated using the full camera frame to obtain the camera matrix and distortion coefficients. Also, assume that I have a 3D world point expressed in that camera's frame.

I know that I can use `cv::projectPoints()` with `rvec=tvec=(0,0,0)`, the camera matrix, and distortion coefficients to project the point to the (full) distorted frame. I also know that if I am receiving an ROI from the camera (which is a cropped portion of the full distorted frame), I can adjust for the ROI simply by subtracting the `(x,y)` coordinate of the top left corner of the ROI from the result of `cv::projectPoints()`. Lastly, I know that if I use `cv::projectPoints()` with `rvec=tvec=(0,0,0)`, the camera matrix, and zero distortion coefficients I can project the point to the full undistorted frame (correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this requires that you use the same camera matrix in `cv::undistort()` and don't use a `newCameraMatrix`).

How do I handle the case where I want to project to the undistorted version of an ROI that I am receiving (i.e. I get a (distorted) ROI and then use `cv::undistort()` on it using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437737/opencv-camera-calibration-of-an-image-crop-roi-submatrix) to account for the fact that it's an ROI, and then I want to project the 3D point to that resulting image)?

If there is a better way to go about all this I am open to suggestions as well. My goal is that I want to be able to project 3D points to distorted and undistorted frames with or without the presence of an ROI where the ROI is always originally defined by the feed from the camera and therefore always defined in the distorted frame (i.e. 4 different cases: distorted full frame, distorted ROI, undistorted full frame, undistorted version of distorted ROI).

Comment: I think you can fake the "ROI-cam" by just adjusting the principal point according to your ROI, e.g. subtracting the ROI's top-left corner from the principal point  Afterwards just use zero distortion coeffs in projectPoints function. Fortunately you can test any optimization against the "long way", whether it gives the same results.

Comment: So are you basically saying that the same solution that I linked to in my question (the one that accounts for an ROI in ```cv::undistort()```) will work for ```cv::projectPoints()```? Meaning that for both the case of the distorted ROI and the undistorted ROI I can just adjust the principle point in the camera matrix and then use ``cv::projectPoints()``` with or without distortion parameters and it'll work itself out? What is the "long way"?

Comment: the long way would be to project on the full size image (with distortion coeffs if necessary) and apply roi afterwards (subtracting top-left from the projected points). Testing whether removal of distortion coeffs gives right results can be done by initIndistortMap and applying the map to the projected points manually.